# Unknown number of elements but I know how many columns I want - fill data from top to bottom

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am fetching unknown number of data elements from the DB.
Each element will be displayed inside some `<div>` with style.

I know that I want to show 4 columns, but fill the data from top to bottom.

so if I get an array: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`

Display it like so:

```
1  4  7  10

2  5  8  11

3  6  9
```

Is there convenient way with bootstrap or I will have to calculate the number of elements first then while iterating them I assign new row/column?

Comment: There could be a better solution but here is an example of what you could do: https://jsfiddle.net/bp145k9u/2/

Comment: thanks, I ended up doing something similar but with a foreach loop since I am using Laravel Blade

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with involves calculating the `elements per column` by dividing `total elements count` with `total columns count` and applying `Math.ceil` on the result. Like you mentioned in your question, you then have to simply iterate through `the number of columns` and `the number of elements per column` and append each element to the proper column.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="row" id="container">
    <div class="col-3">
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    var columns = container.children.length;
    var elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
    
    var elementsPerColumn = Math.ceil(elements.length / columns);
  
    var index = 0;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) { 
        var column = container.children.item(i);
  
        for (var j = 0; j < elementsPerColumn; j++) {    
            var item = elements[index];
                        
            if (item != undefined)
            {
                var divElement = document.createElement('div');
                divElement.classList.add('my-div');
                divElement.innerHTML = item;
                
                column.appendChild(divElement);
            }
            
            index++;
        }  
    }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bp145k9u/2/

(Posting my solution as answer in case someone finds it useful.)